# Workaroud strategies for circular dependencies using only constructor injections

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, circular-dependency

The scope of this question doesn't pertain exclusively to Java. But I have experience coding only in two DI frameworks and both happen to be for Java applications. I.e. Spring and Google Guice. Also, it smells like a beat-up topic and I hope, that more experienced folk should have no problem dropping some related links in the comments.

Anyway, the problem is to allow callbacks for components, which have semantic of children. An example is when you have a GUI application and the topmost window frame component (parent) has references to narrower components like panels and other GUI elements comprising it (children). So far we have this simple picture:

```
(topframe) -> (panel1)
```

But then children components e.g. react on some user interaction and have to request the global repaint. And it turns out to be this call: `topframe.repaint()`

I know only one way to resolve this case and preserve the constructor injection style and it is to introduce a **joining** component. It can be a dedicated manager or an event bus. For the manager it will look something like:

```
@org.springframework.stereotype.Component
public class TopframeManager {
  private java.awt.Component topframe;

  public void setTopframe(java.awt.Component topframe) {
    this.topframe = topframe;
  }

  public java.awt.Component getTopframe() {
    return topframe;
  }
}
```

Now `topframe` can assign itself to the managed field through the setter, while `panel1` can access it lazily through the getter. Now the dependencies look like this:

```
(topframe) -> (panel1)
        |      |
        V      V
       (manager)
```

I prefer this approach to an event bus, because it is applicable for multi-threaded applications, by synchronizing the accessors of the managed field.

Feels like a bandage. Any better way to handle it?

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing apples to oranges.

DI and IoC is inherently *not* event driven in that these dependencies are typically injected at instantiation time, and event driven operations are inherently *not* IoC since the event controls when the object is instantiated, not the DI framework.

This use case/example makes no sense and would be a mish-mash of two entirely different paradigms.  Speaking explicitly to this example, if the flow of code *required* new objects to be instantiated during the lifetime of the application, then something as rigid as dependency injection couldn't dynamically create the instances you need, not unless your DI framework also incorporated some element of event-driven behavior in it (which again, violates the inversion of control principle of DI frameworks in the first place).

Best way to handle it in my head is to establish what it is you're doing with these kinds of components.  Are you letting the DI framework manage this, or are you doing this through event driven operations?  These are mutually exclusive, and can't be papered over with elegant coding solutions.

Comment: This is an interesting way to look at things. But consider this. If what you say was true, then there would be no place for GIN (which is Guice for GWT). GIN is a pure Java DI framework. All GWT applications get transpiled into JavaScript during the compilation. And JavaScript is one of the most event-driven medium you can ever think of.

Answer (score 0):

I came down to the conclusion, that since any valuable real-world UI application utilizes MVC, MVP, or similar devide&conqure pattern, it's better to stick to `EventBus` approach (it can be custom EventBus like the approach used in Guava, or a framework provided one, such as SimpleEventBus in GWT). Then a responsible for this sector of UI controller instance wires up entities like `Panel1` and `MainFrame` via custom events like `RepaintRequestEvent`. This essentially removes any hierarchy among views. The idiom lesson to learn is that regardless of whether we talk about containers or views *dependency-wise* `MainFrame` and `Panel1`  must be related to each other as *siblings*, and not as *parent-child*. To give more clarity this principle can be further exemplified through these snippets:

Bad:

```
@Inject
public MainFrame(Panel1 panel1) {
  add(panel1);
}
```

*dependencies:*

```
(mainFrame)
     |
     V
 (panel1)
```

Good:

```
private final MainFrame mainFrame;
private final Panel1 panel1;

@Inject
public HelloPageTopLayout(MainFrame mainFrame, Panel1 panel1) {
  this.mainFrame = mainFrame;
  this.panel1 = panel1;
}

public void go() {
  mainFrame.removeAll();
  mainFrame.add(panel1);
}
```

*dependencies:*

```
    (ApplicationLayout)
       |          |
       V          V
 (mainFrame)   (panel1)
```

Bad:

```
@Inject
public Panel1(final MainFrameManager mainFrameManager) {
  ...
  slider.addChangeListener(e -> {
    ...
    mainFrameManager.getMainFrame().repaint();
  });
}
```

*dependencies:*

```
(mainFrame) -> (panel1)
         |      |
         V      V
     (mainFrameManager)
```

Good:

```
@Inject
public Panel1Controller(final EventBus eventBus, Panel1 panel1) {
  panel1.getSlider().addChangeListener(e -> {
    ...
    eventBus.post(new RepaintRequestEvent());
  });
}
```

and

```
@Inject
public MainFrame(EventBus eventBus) {
  eventBus.register(this);
}

@Subscribe(Application.EVENT_BUS_NAME)
public void onRepaint(RepaintRequestEvent event) {
  this.repaint();
}
```

*dependencies:*

```
(mainFrame)    (panel1)
         |      |
         V      V
        (eventBus)
```